# How to add a month to an Excel date value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I tried to google for a while but it seems to have no straight forward way to do this math.

For example, we have the date at B2 `12/31/2012` and need to add 2 months to it and store value in B4. What is the direct formula to use? I rather not using any 3rd party addon(s).

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Using EDATE function as @Toni Toni Chopper answer below is what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Still, please improve you questions so other people with similar problem can find it and use that solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/excel-help/add-or-subtract-dates-HP010342155.aspx#BM5

> You can use the EDATE function to quickly add or subtract a specific
>   number of whole months to or from a date.
>
> The EDATE function requires two values (also referred to as
>   arguments): the start date and the number of months that you want to
>   add or subtract. To subtract months, enter a negative number as the
>   second argument (for example, =EDATE("2/15/10",-5). This formula
>   results in the date 9/15/09.